# Error: AppLoader(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Да возможно уже были похожие проблемы, но ещё не видел такую связанную с React Native.

```
MainScreen.js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useCallback } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Image, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { AddTodo } from "../components/AddTodo";
import { Todo } from "../components/Todo";
import { THEME } from "../theme";
import { TodoContext } from "../context/todo/todoContext";
import { ScreenContext } from "../context/screen/screenContext";
import { AppLoader } from "../components/ui/AppLoader";
import { AppText } from "../components/ui/AppText";
import { AppButton } from "../components/ui/AppButton";

export const MainScreen = () => {
  const { todos, addTodo, removeTodo, fetchTodos, loading, error } = useContext(
    TodoContext
  );
  const { changeScreen } = useContext(ScreenContext);
  const [deviceWidth, setDeviceWidth] = useState(
    Dimensions.get("window").width - THEME.PADDING_HORIZONTAL * 2
  );

  const loadTodos = useCallback(async () => await fetchTodos(), [fetchTodos]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadTodos();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const update = () => {
      const width =
        Dimensions.get("window").width - THEME.PADDING_HORIZONTAL * 2;
      setDeviceWidth(width);
    };

    Dimensions.addEventListener("change", update);

    return () => {
      Dimensions.removeEventListener("change", update);
    };
  });
  
  if (loading) {
    return <AppLoader/>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.center}>
        <AppText style={styles.error}>{error}</AppText>
        <AppButton onPress={loadTodos}>Повторить</AppButton>
      </View>
    );
  }

  let content = (
    <View style={{ width: deviceWidth }}>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        data={todos}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Todo todo={item} onRemove={removeTodo} onOpen={changeScreen} />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );

  if (todos.length === 0) {
    content = (
      <View style={styles.imgWrap}>
        <Image
          style={styles.img}
          source={require("../../assets/no-items.png")}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
 
  return (
    <View>
      <AddTodo onSubmit={addTodo} />
      {content}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imgWrap: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 10,
    height: 300,
  },
  img: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    resizeMode: "contain",
  },
  center: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  error: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: THEME.DANGER_COLOR,
    marginBottom: 10
  },
});
```

И ошибка возникает в рендере AppLoader

```
AppLoader.js
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { THEME } from "../../theme";

export const AppLoader = () => {
  <View style={styles.center}>
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={THEME.MAIN_COLOR} />
  </View>
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  center: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

Файл MainScreen.js дальше идёт в основной шаблон и потом выходит в App.js
Как исправить рендер AppLoader?

Answer (score 2):

Замените фигурные скобки на круглые, ваш компонент ничего не возвращает

```
export const AppLoader = () => (
  <View style={styles.center}>
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={THEME.MAIN_COLOR} />
  </View>
);
```